# Why are values from db loaded differently on Console Apps and WebAPIs?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I've been using a DbContext (MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore 6.10.6) on a WebAPI project (.NET Core 2.0) for quite a while without any problems but now I need to use the same context on a Console Application and special characters aren't being loaded correctly.

**WebAPI:**

```
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _context;

    public ProductsController(MyDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        var productName = _context.Products
            .Single(x => x.Id == 1)
            .Name;

        return productName; = // "PÃO FRANCÊS"
    }
}
```

**Console App:**

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // setup DI
    Initialize();

    var context = ServiceProvider.GetService<MyDbContext>();

    var productName = context.Products
        .Single(x => x.Id == 1)
        .Name;

    Console.WriteLine(productName); // "P�O FRANC�S"
}
```

Why are these values different even though the same context is used?

**Update 1:**
Changing the Console.OutputEncoding to UTF8 or changing the console font to Lucidas Console or Console didn't change the result. The real purpose of the Console App is to call an API and the result has the � character as soon as I retrieve the value from the DB when debugging. I don't need to print the result on the console.

**Update 2:**
When debugging past the `productName` variable, the value doesn't change when calling `productName` or `?productName` in the Immediate Window from Visual Studio.

**Update 3:**
I've configured a test database using MS SQL Server and the characters are loaded correctly. It looks like it's a problem with MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore

**Update 4:**
Tested it with a new Console App using .NET Framework 4.7.1 and the characters are displayed correctly.

Comment: can you check and ensure defaultThreadCulture is same in both cases ?

Comment: I tried both en-US and pt-BR but it doesn't change the result on either the Console App or WebAPI project.

Comment: Please debug past the `productName` assignment, and then do `?productName` in the Immediate Window of Visual Studio. Update your post with the values (from both app types).

Comment: `Update 2: When debugging past the productName variable, the value doesn't change when calling productName or ?productName in the Immediate Window from Visual Studio.` So, to be clear, both the console and other app are correctly assigning `PÃO FRANCÊS` to `productName`?

Comment: That's correct. In the Console App both productName and ?productName display "P�O FRANC�S" and in the WebAPI project they both display "PÃO FRANCÊS"

Comment: Any idea why the question was downvoted? What can I do to improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to add this line to the console app.

```
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
```

Reference: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/10054

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to get the special characters to load correctly.

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
```

Comment: I tried that but it's still not showing the correct characters.

Comment: Did you add it before executing Console.WriteLine() ? Please simply try Console.WriteLine("PÃO FRANCÊS"); with above output encoding and see whether it works.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("PÃO FRANCÊS");` works fine, even without setting the  OutputEncoding value